# "À moi" ou "de moi": Différences ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

> C'est une attestation de moi.

contre

> C'est une attestation à moi.

Quelle(s) est(sont) la(les) différence(s) entre ces deux tournures ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C'est une attestation de moi.

C'est moi qui ai écrit l'attestation.

> C'est une attestation à moi.

L'attestation m'appartient. (Tournure populaire)

Ces phrases seraient plus idiomatiques en modifiant la première partie :

> Cette attestation est de moi.

> Cette attestation est à moi.